# Proper way to alert user of iOS app issue

Tags: android, ios, error-handling

When developing Java apps used internally by users in the company I work for, I would have the app display a message such as "An issue occurred.  Please contact the Help Desk and report it", when an issue occurs with the app that is being used.

Now that I am learning to develop mobile apps on my own, I am faced with the question of how best to handle app issues in this environment, since there really isn't a help desk.

My initial thought was to asynchronously call a service to log the error.  But, remote communication may not be possible.  Then, I thought to display an error alert with a number to contact or e-mail address to mail to report the issue.  But, is that really best practice?

So, for mobile apps, what is the best practice for capturing issues or having users report them, so that they can be properly addressed and not have them become very frustrated with your app, especially if the root cause may be related to something that is out of your control, such as an issue with a godaddy server, which hosts a database used by the app?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Crashes? Use Crashlytics (now Fabric.io), if other kind... Probably an alert (`UIAlertController`). If communication is not possible, you may save the data (for example in `NSUserDefaults`) and send it asynchronously when an Internet connection is detected (maybe using Reachability). I don't really understand where the problem is. The usual behavior is showing a message ("an error has occured... Try again").

Comment: As a side note: It's a bad practice to ask your user to go outside of the app to report problems. They should be handled by the app itself. Horrible UX. You want your users to do the less possible actions to make your app work.

Answer (score 0):

For recording crashes, you could use Crashlytics, so that you can see the device log when that crash occurred and investigate the reasons to improve your app / prevent the crash from happening again in the future, or reaching out directly to the specific user (as you could record user id / email addr in Crashlytics) if you for instance see the app crashes for her/him repeatedly.

For issues/problems the app experienced (but it didn't crash), you can use things like Rollbar to record the incidents. You can put special logic in your app, especially places that are prone to failure, or whenever your app recognizes "an issue".

If you want to have a place *in your app* that users could search for FAQs, ask questions or provide feedback and concerns, you may want to use things like UserVoice to provide a central hub.

[Things aforementioned may not be free software.]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Crashlytics and if you do not want to go for third party then you can read all of your logs from iOS SDK for your app,so you can go for it as well
or there is always solution with third party softwares